# d3js:The xaxis time is not showing the complete date value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a multichart plot: [see code](http://jsfiddle.net/cfk8Y/8/), that:
1.takes a 2D array that contains multiples values of time and others propreties

```
var values=[
 ["2011-10-01 20:46:04",63.4,42.7,12.2,44.2],
 ["2012-10-01 20:46:04",75.42,32.78.2.82.2],
 ["2013-10-01 20:46:04",73.4,20.7,92.2,75,4]
];
```

2.takes an array of the propreties names

> var items=['Happy','Sad','Angry','Surprised'];

3.build a json array that contains all items names and values

```
var data = [
{"Year":"2011-10-01 20:46:04","Happy":63.4,"Sad":42.7,"Angry":12.2,"Surprised":44.2},
{"Year":"2012-10-01 20:46:04","Happy":75.4,"Sad":32.7,"Angry":78.2,"Surprised":82.2},
{"Year":"2013-10-01 20:46:04","Happy":73.4,"Sad":20.7,"Angry":92.2,"Surprised":75.4}];
```

4.Using the data array the code plot a multichart graph with xaxis=date values,yaxis=other values in data array except the date values, the code work fine but the problem is once I introduce date values that vary very slow(in seconds) the axis axis dont show the complete date value despite the xaxis takes the date value as a variable,and it works fine with date values with a important variations but doesnt for small variations of time.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. How do you want the output that the code you've linked to produces be different?

Comment: The xaxis values:date is not displayed in the complete format,exp:2013-10-08 18:36:25 is only showing :20 or :30(seconds)despite the same code works fine(displays the complete date value)for data array with big variation in the time values(you can test the first commented array to see the difference in the xaxis behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of how the default time tick formatter is set up -- see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales). You can change this by introducing your own custom multi-scale time format, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176). The relevant code is this:

```
var customTimeFormat = timeFormat([
  [d3.time.format("%Y"), function() { return true; }],
  [d3.time.format("%B"), function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
  [d3.time.format("%b %d"), function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
  [d3.time.format("%a %d"), function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
  [d3.time.format("%I %p"), function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
  [d3.time.format("%I:%M"), function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
  [d3.time.format(":%S"), function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
  [d3.time.format(".%L"), function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }]
]);

function timeFormat(formats) {
  return function(date) {
    var i = formats.length - 1, f = formats[i];
    while (!f[1](date)) f = formats[--i];
    return f[0](date);
  };
}
```

This will iterate over the time formats, starting with the most specific (smallest) one until the function in the second argument returns a value that evaluates to true. This way, you can check what date range is significant. If, for example, everything up to hours is zero, then the changes are only in the days and it's not necessary to show anything smaller than that.

I've changed this for your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cfk8Y/9/) to include hour and minute as well, but you'll notice that the tick labels for the bottom graph overlap now. You can of course use different multi-scale time formats for all of the axes.

Comment: Thank you Lars for the explanation :)